# Python UDP socket send and receive data at the same time

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm creating a simple socket server using UDP in Python and I want to add some notion of reliability by having the receiver send ACKs. My sender will have to send data and receive these ACKs at the same time. What is the preferred way of doing this? Should I make both a sending and receiving thread, use some kind of nonblocking calls, or something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you can't just use TCP, eliminating the need to do this?

Comment: It's a requirement imposed by the class I'm taking. I wish I could though!

Comment: You can do it on a single thread. Events will be queued for a certain amount of time. As long as you read them fast enough it should be good on a single thread.

Comment: A single thread, non-blocking I/O, and select() is sufficient for this, as long as your thread doesn't spend a lot of time doing calculations (etc) during event loops.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple solutions for this:

- The simplest solution is in stdlib, the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) module which has a UDPServer - you can set handlers for different message types and enable your state machine that way. There's also a bunch of nifty mixins for threads and other behaviors.
- Third-party module [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) which uses libevent for async network programming is another solution.
- You could write something at the raw socket level with [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy) but that puts all the heavy lifting on you, although there are undoubtedly examples of how to do what you want.